# Every object of the topos $Sh(B)$ is projective

Tags: category-theory, boolean-algebra, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

Let $B$ be a complete boolian algebra, then every object of the topos $Sh(B)$ of sheaves on $B$ is projective.

This is exercise 4.15.d of the book sheaves in geometry and logic.

Do I have to show that every object of the topos $Sh(B)$ is a retract of a sum of representatives?

Comment: Even if you could show that every object is a retract of a coproduct of representable sheaves, you would still need to show that representable sheaves are projective.

Comment: Would you please explain the relation between these two?

Comment: If every sheaf is projective then in particular representable sheaves are projective. Coproducts of projective objects are projective, and retracts of projective objects are projective, but if you don't know that representable sheaves are projective then what good is it to show that every sheaf is a retract of coproducts of representables?

Comment: This is part d of the exercise, I have already proved part c ,and I want to know if I can use it  in this part but I don't know how are they related to each other....  part c says: Show that in case $E$ is a presheaf topos , then an object $P$ of $E$ is projec-tive iff $P$ is a retract of a sum of representables. (Hence presheaf topoi have enough projectives.)

Comment: Yes, representable presheaves are projective. So what? Projectives in the category of presheaves are a priori different from projectives in the category of sheaves.

Comment: I don't really know how should I think about this.....would you please show me some tips?

Comment: You could start by showing that representable sheaves on a complete boolean algebra are projective, I suppose.

Comment: So in other words, $Sh(B)$ satisfies the axiom of choice.  Did this problem come up in the context of forcing using sheaf theory, perhaps?

Comment: No, there was nothing about forcing as I read the book.....(I don't know if there is such a relation...)

Comment: I don't know if there's a relation either - it probably depends on the topology on $Psh(B)$ used to construct the sheaf category $Sh(B)$, and I don't know off the top of my head what topology is being used here.  If it's related to the Grothendieck site like topology where covers are "dense below" sets, then that's very much in the flavor of forcing theory (though also, I'm very rusty on the boolean algebra formulation of forcing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this answer assumes that $Sh(B)$ is the category of sheaves where $B$ is considered as a locale, i.e. the presheaves $\mathscr{F}$ on the poset category of $B$ such that whenever $\bigvee_{i\in I} c_i = b$ and $f_i \in \mathscr{F}(c_i)$ satisfy $f_i |_{c_i \wedge c_j} = f_j |_{c_i \wedge c_j}$, then there exists a unique $f \in \mathscr{F}(b)$ such that $f |_{c_i} = f_i$.  If that does not match the definition the problem is using, let me know and I can delete the answer.

---

Here is an outline of the proof: suppose we have an epimorphism $\phi : \mathscr{G} \to \mathscr{G}''$ and a morphism $g : \mathscr{F} \to \mathscr{G}''$.  We now consider the partial order where objects are ordered pairs of a subsheaf $\mathscr{F}' \subseteq \mathscr{F}$ and a lifting $\tilde g : \mathscr{F}' \to \mathscr{G}$ such that $\phi \circ \tilde g = g |_{\mathscr{F}'}$; and the ordering is given by extension i.e. $(\mathscr{F}_1', \tilde g_1) \le (\mathscr{F}_2', \tilde g_2)$ is and only if $\mathscr{F}_1' \subseteq \mathscr{F}_2'$ and $\tilde g_1 = \tilde g_2 |_{\mathscr{F}_1'}$.

First, it is relatively straightforward to show that any chain $C$ in this partial order has an upper bound where $\mathscr{F}' = \bigcup_{(\mathscr{F}_i', \tilde g_i) \in C} \mathscr{F}_i'$ and $\tilde g$ is given by gluing the $\tilde g_i$.  Therefore, by Zorn's Lemma, the partial order has a maximal element.  We claim that this maximal element has $\mathscr{F}' = \mathscr{F}$, so that the $\tilde g$ component will be the desired lifting $\mathscr{F} \to \mathscr{G}$.

To see this, suppose to the contrary that for some $b \in B$ and some $x \in \mathscr{F}(b)$, $x \not\in \mathscr{F}'(b)$.  Then let $c \le b$ be the maximum element such that $x |_c \in \mathscr{F}'(c)$, and let $c' := b \wedge \overline{c}$.  Then since $\mathscr{G} \to \mathscr{G}''$ is an epimorphism, there exists a covering of $d_i \le c'$ with $\bigvee_{i\in I} d_i = c'$ and sections $y_i \in \mathscr{G}(d_i)$ such that $\phi(y_i) = f(x)|_{d_i}$.  Since $c' \ne \bot$, we must have some $d_i \ne \bot$.  Then, for this $i$, we can form an extension of $\tilde g$ to $\mathscr{F}' \cup \{ x|_{d_i} \}$ with $\tilde g'(x|_{d_i}) = y_i$ (where the essential point is that the union is a disjoint union since $d_i \wedge c = \bot$), which contradicts the assumed maximality of $(\mathscr{F}', \tilde g)$.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually find the solution later in the same book. Proposition VI.1.8 states that all epimorphisms split in a topos $T$ if it is generated by subobjects of $1$ and if for all $E \in T,$ $Sub(E)$ is a complete Boolean algebra. The proof is essentially what Daniel Schepler provided here: the maximal subobject for which a section of a given epi exists has to be the epi's codomain itself.

As in (i) of your exercise, $A \twoheadrightarrow P$ splits $\forall A$ iff $P$ is projective. It's also not hard to ensure that the assumptions of the proposition hold.

That subobjects of $1$ generate follows immediately from the facts that any presheaf is a colimit of representables and sheafification $a$ preserves subobjects and colimits (in *"Sheaves ..."* it is at the end of III.6, p. 139): $P \simeq aiP \simeq a\varinjlim yU_i \simeq \varinjlim a yU_i, a yU_i \in Sub_{Sh}(1).$

To see that $Sub(E)$ is a complete Boolean algebra, note that, as in III.8 (21), it is indeed the case when a topology is the dense topology on a poset. This is exactly our case. Alternatively, you can for a subsheaf $Q \in Sub(E)$ construct its negation $\bar{Q}$ explicitly. The classifying map for $Q$, $S \to \Omega = \{ \text{principal sieves} \} ,$ assigns to $s \in S(A)$ the maximal algebra object $U \subset A$ on which the restriction of $s$ falls into $Q(-).$ (Note that $\Omega$ is a Boolean algebra.) Compose the classifying map with the negation map $\neg \colon \Omega\to \Omega$ to get the classifying map of $\bar{Q}$. It's not hard to see that $Q \lor \bar{Q} = E$.